# If statement constantly activating in android

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am working on some code that will allow the program to check if the user has entered a name and a birth day and decide if the birthday is today and play happy birthday. However while I have managed to get the program to use the correct date and play the songs the if statements do not seem to be working properly. When ever I enter the current date as the birthday the happy birthday song always starts up even when the name box is empty and it should ask for your name. This only happens when the birthday textbox and the current day match, so could anyone help me to get my if statement working correctly. Here is my if statement code.

```
if((btn==v) && (name.getText().toString()!="") && (bday.getText().toString()!="") && (bday.getText().toString().equals(formatdate))){
        String msg1 = "Today is " + sdf.format(cdate.getTime()) + ". Happy Birthday, " + name.getText() + "!";
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        //Context context = null;           

        mp.start();
        //mp.stop();
        response.setText(msg1);         
    }else if(btn==v && name.getText().toString().equals("") && bday.getText().toString()!=""){
        String msg3 = "Please enter your name.";
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        mp.stop();
        response.setText(msg3);             
    }else if(btn==v && name.getText().toString()!="" && bday.getText().toString().equals("")){
        String msg4 = "Please enter your birthday.";
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        response.setText(msg4);
    }else if(btn==v && name.getText().toString().equals("") && bday.getText().toString().equals("")){
        String msg5 = "Please enter your name and birthday.";
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg5, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        response.setText(msg5);
    }else{
        String msg2 = "Today is " + formatdate + ". Sorry today is not your birthday.";
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        response.setText(msg2);
    }
```

Comment: First thing to do is to stop comparing strings with `!= ""` plus all your conditions start with `btn == v && name.getText()` - you should do that as one statement before the rest - you code will be easier to follow then and you might spot the issue quicker.

Comment: I'd encourage you to learn about logging/logcat/adb so that you can debug this, and future, problems more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you need to change. You don't need to do this:

```
name.getText().toString()
```

You can get rid of the toString() part.

Second. Instead of doing something like this:

```
name.getText().toString()!=""
```

Change it to this:

```
!name.getText().equals("")
```

Because `.equals()` returns a boolean and you can't compare strings with `==` or `!=` etc.

Finally, you need to make sure not to use `b == v` but `b.equals(v)`

Answer (score 0):

> In Java the == operator is a simple comparison of **values**. For
>   object references, the values are the **references**, so x == y
>   returns true if x and y reference the same object.

1. no need of `toString()` for `getText()` since it itself returns string.
2. change `bday.getText().toString()!=""` to `!bday.getText().equals("")`
3. change  `name.getText().toString()!=""` to `!name.getText().equals("")`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the "!=" operator. In Java, the operator "==" and "!=" only compare if the referenced object is equal. It means the object only "==" itself. While the ".equals()" function compares the content of two objects. You should always use "equals()" function to compare the content of two objects.
use

```
btn.euqals(v);
!name.getText().toString().equals("");
```

instead.